# Issue Parsing XML From MtConnect Stream, Unsure How To Access Specific Node Value

Tags: python, xml

Edit: My particular issue was overlooking namespaces, combined with below answer provided a solution.

Attempting to parse and store an XML response from an Mt Connect Agent, unsure how to access a specific piece of data in the node. Trying to access and isolate the '100' immediately after the override term.

It doesn't come up as an attribute, i can't pass the parent node to get the value. i'm sure it's simple but i'm new to xml and programming in general, not sure where to find the answer. Any help or direction appreciated.

snippet of source xml:

```
<AxisFeedrate dataItemId="rovrd" timestamp="2021-03-22T19:26:22.643Z" sequence="7" name="RapidOverride" subType="OVERRIDE">100</AxisFeedrate>
```

code:

```
import xml.sax

class GroupHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):

        def startElement(self, name, attrs):
            
            self.current = name
       
            if self.current == "AxisFeedrate":
                    print("-----AxisFeedrate-----")
                    print("dataItemId = {}".format(attrs['dataItemId']))
                    print("timestamp = {}".format(attrs['timestamp']))
                    print("sequence = {}".format(attrs['sequence']))
                    print("name = {}".format(attrs['name']))
                    print("subType = {}".format(attrs['subType']))


handler = GroupHandler()
parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
parser.parse('umc500_xml_sample.xml')'''
```

Result:

```
-----AxisFeedrate-----
dataItemId = rovrd
timestamp = 2021-03-22T19:26:22.643Z
sequence = 7
name = RapidOverride
subType = OVERRIDE
```

Comment: Do you have to use SAX?

Comment: no, this was merely the first attempt and semi working. I'm working through elementtree and minidom docs atm but having trouble there too.

Comment: see my answer. it works using ElementTree

Comment: Interesting, i could never get it to work on the full XML document but works fine on my snippet? i'm wondering if the format is off? I wanted to avoid adding a wall of text but, added the complete XML to the main post. Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: If my solution works for you - feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: @balderman I went over the ElementTree docs agian and realised i had overlooked namespaces. once i account for those your soloution worked fine. Thanks agian for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<AxisFeedrate dataItemId="rovrd" timestamp="2021-03-22T19:26:22.643Z" sequence="7" name="RapidOverride" subType="OVERRIDE">100</AxisFeedrate>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.text)
```

output

```
100
```